# i have a prob with string replacing in batch

Tags: encryption, batch-file, cmd

i am trying to make my own encryption for .dll files.
but it wont work like i want it too can annyone help.

---

```
@echo off
set /p lol=(
echo %lol%>test.dll
for /f "tokens=*" %%j in (test.dll) do set f1=%%j
set f1=%f1:a=QUE%
set f1=%f1:b=GUI%
set f1=%f1:c=DOP%
set f1=%f1:d=EXO%
set f1=%f1:e=CUI%
set f1=%f1:f=RAY%
set f1=%f1:g=TAI%
set f1=%f1:h=YAM%
set f1=%f1:i=*+=%
set f1=%f1:j=UIT%
set f1=%f1:k=ITO%
set f1=%f1:l=ORC%
set f1=%f1:m=KIP%
set f1=%f1:n=JAA%
set f1=%f1:o=(.)%
set f1=%f1:p=)Y(%
set f1=%f1:q=!i!%
set f1=%f1:r=$S$%
set f1=%f1:s=WPL%
set f1=%f1:t=%*/%
set f1=%f1:u=FOL%
set f1=%f1:v=FUK%
set f1=%f1:w=@.@%
set f1=%f1:x=S$$%
set f1=%f1:y=^.^%
set f1=%f1:z=AAP%
set f1=%f1:A=qal%
set f1=%f1:B=gal%
set f1=%f1:C=dor%
set f1=%f1:D=ert%
set f1=%f1:E=332%
set f1=%f1:F=rat%
set f1=%f1:G=pok%
set f1=%f1:H=yap%
set f1=%f1:I=8-)%
set f1=%f1:J=uki%
set f1=%f1:K=ipa%
set f1=%f1:L=o:)%
set f1=%f1:M=kop%
set f1=%f1:N=jas%
set f1=%f1:O=911%
set f1=%f1:P=007%
set f1=%f1:Q=112%
set f1=%f1:R=4gh%
set f1=%f1:S=wrq%
set f1=%f1:T=5hi%
set f1=%f1:U=777%
set f1=%f1:V=gak%
set f1=%f1:W=2g2%
set f1=%f1:X=dom%
set f1=%f1:Y=666%
set f1=%f1:Z=aal%
set f1=%f1:0=ugb%
set f1=%f1:1=zup%
set f1=%f1:2=xfi%
set f1=%f1:3=cmv%
set f1=%f1:4=vui%
set f1=%f1:5=but%
set f1=%f1:6=nom%
set f1=%f1:7=mon%
set f1=%f1:8=hub%
set f1=%f1:9=whn%
set f1=%f1:!=ZIP%
set f1=%f1:@=XLO%
set f1=%f1:$=CVB%
set f1=%f1:%=VQE%
set f1=%f1:^=BUY%
set f1=%f1:&=NAM%
set f1=%f1:*=MAL%
set f1=%f1:(=LAL%
set f1=%f1:)=JN9%
set f1=%f1:#=255%
set f1=%f1:_=?19%
set f1=%f1:-={GT%
set f1=%f1:==SC}%
set f1=%f1:+=J~L%
set f1=%f1:\=;RT%
set f1=%f1:|=:OP%
set f1=%f1:{=KAA%
set f1=%f1:}=KAL%
set f1=%f1:[=PLO%
set f1=%f1:]=DQW%
set f1=%f1::=PIP%
set f1=%f1:;=AR9%
set f1=%f1:"=UNF%
set f1=%f1:'=CNP%
set f1=%f1:<=JMN%
set f1=%f1:>=HBH%
set f1=%f1:,=25J%
set f1=%f1:.=YF7%
set f1=%f1:/=UYG%
set f1=%f1:?=DFG%
set f1=%f1:`=PUY%
set f1=%f1:~=CV7%
echo %f1%>test.dll
pause
exit
```

---

Comment: "but it wont work like i want it too" - and exactly how do you want it _to_ work? You should always provide the following: (1) the minimal code sample that exhibits the problem, (2) what it _is_ doing; and (3) what you _expect_ it to do.

Comment: i want it to take the input and change it for example a=QUE so it cant be read but for some reson the file just closes it makes the file but when i open it it shows exactly what i typed. so siply said it should encript my input and write it to a file. PS: this has to work on all texst numbers and sighns i would like it if i could change space and enter aswell but this string replacement is new for me :P thx in advance, Henry

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I am not sure what is intended with the code snippet. First, a redirection of > will clear off all contents of the dll file. Next, I suspect any of your commands in the set block after the first echo would get a chance to execute. Certainly, the %lol% variable will never get a value within the block, it will be evaluated before executing anything within the set block unless delayedexpansion is enabled. Try [enabling delayedexpansion.](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Put this on top:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

and qualify all %var%'s to !var!

Hope this post could give you some sort of start for you to achieve what you are upto.

Answer (score 0):

First the complete idea is nice but worthless, as it can't be done with batch alone.
At least you can't read a NUL (0x00) character with batch.

Why your code can't works has many reasons, you read from test.dll while trying to write it simultaneously, how do you expect that it could work?

Your code doesn't handle any special characters, it's possible with batch but it's tricky.

The line `set f1=%f1:*=MAL%` can't work, as you can't replace a single star this way.
Also `set f1=%f1:==SC}%` and `set f1=%f1:~=CV7%`
 will fail by the same reason.

`set f1=%f1:%=VQE%` changes `f1` always to `=VQE` independent of the content of `f1`.

Even if you remove these lines, your translation translates each character multiple times, the input `a` results to the output of

`ZIPhubKAAGTJN9ZIPvuighabuthiwhnzupzupwhnzupzupPIPJN9cmvcmvxfivuighbuthiwhnzupzupvuighvuighabuthiwhnzupzupwhnzupzupPIPJN9*J~L=*UYG`

To find such problems it's always a good idea to remove the `exit` and to enable `echo on`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's fixed or more broken, but I got it to output this:

```
CVBXLOYF7XLOugbugbmonwhnzupzupPIPJN9CVBvuighabuthiwhnzupzupwhnzupzupPIPJN9cmvcmvxfivuighbuthiwhnzupzupvuighvuighabuthiwhnzupzupwhnzupzupPIPJN9*J~L=cmvcmvxfivuighbuthiwhnzupzupvuighvuighabuthiwhnzupzupwhnzupzupPIPJN9*J~L=xfigxfirqCVBCVBLALYF7JN9vuighabuthiwhnzupzupwhnzupzupPIPJN9cmvcmvxfivuighbuthiwhnzupzupvuighvuighabuthiwhnzupzupwhnzupzupPIPJN9*J~L=*/
```

Again, not sure if it worked or not, but I did use :

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

Is there a way you have established for reversing this?

```
REM @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p lol=(
echo %lol%>test.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%j in (test.txt) do set f1=%%j
set f1=%f1:a=QUE%
set f1=%f1:b=GUI%
set f1=%f1:c=DOP%
set f1=%f1:d=EXO%
set f1=%f1:e=CUI%
set f1=%f1:f=RAY%
set f1=%f1:g=TAI%
set f1=%f1:h=YAM%
set f1=%f1:i=*+=%
set f1=%f1:j=UIT%
set f1=%f1:k=ITO%
set f1=%f1:l=ORC%
set f1=%f1:m=KIP%
set f1=%f1:n=JAA%
set f1=%f1:o=(.)%
set f1=%f1:p=)Y(%
set f1=%f1:q=!i!%
set f1=%f1:r=$S$%
set f1=%f1:s=WPL%
set f1=%f1:t=%*/%
set f1=%f1:u=FOL%
set f1=%f1:v=FUK%
set f1=%f1:w=@.@%
set f1=%f1:x=S$$%
set f1=%f1:y=^.^%
set f1=%f1:z=AAP%
set f1=%f1:A=qal%
set f1=%f1:B=gal%
set f1=%f1:C=dor%
set f1=%f1:D=ert%
set f1=%f1:E=332%
set f1=%f1:F=rat%
set f1=%f1:G=pok%
set f1=%f1:H=yap%
set f1=%f1:I=8-)%
set f1=%f1:J=uki%
set f1=%f1:K=ipa%
set f1=%f1:L=o:)%
set f1=%f1:M=kop%
set f1=%f1:N=jas%
set f1=%f1:O=911%
set f1=%f1:P=007%
set f1=%f1:Q=112%
set f1=%f1:R=4gh%
set f1=%f1:S=wrq%
set f1=%f1:T=5hi%
set f1=%f1:U=777%
set f1=%f1:V=gak%
set f1=%f1:W=2g2%
set f1=%f1:X=dom%
set f1=%f1:Y=666%
set f1=%f1:Z=aal%
set f1=%f1:0=ugb%
set f1=%f1:1=zup%
set f1=%f1:2=xfi%
set f1=%f1:3=cmv%
set f1=%f1:4=vui%
set f1=%f1:5=but%
set f1=%f1:6=nom%
set f1=%f1:7=mon%
set f1=%f1:8=hub%
set f1=%f1:9=whn%
set f1=%f1:!=ZIP%
set f1=%f1:@=XLO%
set f1=%f1:$=CVB%
set f1=%f1:^%=VQE%
set f1=%f1:^=BUY%
set f1=%f1:&=NAM%
set f1=%f1:^*=MAL%
set f1=%f1:(=LAL%
set f1=%f1:)=JN9%
set f1=%f1:#=255%
set f1=%f1:_=?19%
set f1=%f1:-={GT%
set f1=%f1:^==SC}%
set f1=%f1:+=J~L%
set f1=%f1:\=;RT%
set f1=%f1:|=:OP%
set f1=%f1:{=KAA%
set f1=%f1:}=KAL%
set f1=%f1:[=PLO%
set f1=%f1:]=DQW%
set f1=%f1::=PIP%
set f1=%f1:;=AR9%
set f1=%f1:"=UNF%
set f1=%f1:'=CNP%
set f1=%f1:<=JMN%
set f1=%f1:>=HBH%
set f1=%f1:,=25J%
set f1=%f1:.=YF7%
set f1=%f1:^/=UYG%
set f1=%f1:?=DFG%
set f1=%f1:`=PUY%
set f1=%f1:^~=CV7%
echo %f1%>test.txt
pause
```

I had to use (^) to escape some characters you had that were messing up the output.

Comment: What do you expect that the EnableDelayedExpansion would change? You don't use it.

Comment: Ya, I put it in to do some testing with it, but then forgot to take it out afterwards.